# LARAVEL 8 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel

При изменении идентификатора он сохраняет, но когда я удаляю полностью идентификатор он не возвращает прошлое значение а выдает ошибку, почему?

```
public function store(BlogCategoryCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->input();
        if (empty($data['slug'])) {
            $data['slug'] = Str::slug($data['title']);
        }

        $item = (new BlogCategory())->create($data);

        if ($item) {
            return redirect()->route('blog.admin.categories.edit', [$item->id])->with(['success' => 'Успешно сохранено']);
        } else {
            return back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Ошибка сохранения'])->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Очень интересное создание конечно=))) `BlogCategroy::create($data)` как то всё же по приятней=))) Попробуйте увеличить авто инкремент у таблицы модели в базе

Comment: $table->bigincrements('id'); так по умолчанию вроде стоит кол-во символов 255, разве нет? я новичок))))